# Does Android Studio somehow cache Firebase data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Currently learning Firebase and came up against an odd issue. Essentially Android Studio was complaining it couldn't convert a `long` to a `String` even though the field was stored as a string and the variable was set as a string.

After a long drawn out debug process, I completely recreated the data manually, the new data was exactly the same, only the name of the collection was changed.

I referenced the new collection and it worked straight away. The only thing I can think of is that some fields started as numbers but I changed them to strings. Perhaps it was still somehow holding on to the old data types?

If this is the case, how can I prevent it from happening or is there a way of clearing some cached data somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have consistent data and to avoid errors like that, you should store in a single property a value of a same type within each node if you are using Firebase Realtime database or under each document if you are using Cloud Firestore.

And this is because there is no way in Java in which you can simply cast a variable of type `long` to a `String`. Note, there has nothing to do with the cached data.

Comment: Yeah I get that bit but at the time of the error, the types matched so there should have been no reason for the error, I think. It was only when the new collection was created with the same data and data types that the error disappeared.

Comment: I'm still not sure why 2 identical sets of data produce different results.

Comment: But there are not identical. If one is added as a long and the other one is added a String on the same property, you get that behaviour, that's why I said, you need to have the same type of data on that particular property across your collection. Is it clear now?